# Degree of irreducible representation of group with abelian subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, proof-explanation, representation-theory

I'm reading in Serre book linear representations of finite groups.
In the $3^{rd}$ chapter, there is the next claim: If G group with $A \leq G$ abelian subgroup, then the degree of every irr representaion of G is bounded by $\frac{|G|}{|A|}$. 
In the last part of the proof, we find an subrepresentation of irr representation, given by $V'=Span(\rho_s(W)_{s \in G} $, where W is irr rep of A (hence of dimension 1). Since the original representation was irr. it follows that V' is our representation. Now, since W is invarian under A, it follows that $V'= Span(\rho_s(W))_{s \not\in A}$. Serra concludes that $dim(V')\leq\frac{|G|}{|A|}$, when I see in that point that it's only bounded by $|G|-|A|$. Can some one explain what do I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Serre does is to observe that, if $g\in G$, $a\in A$ and $w\in W$, then$$(ga)w=g\overbrace{(aw)}^{\phantom W\in W}\in gW.$$So, $V'$ is spanned by a set with $\frac{|G|}{|A|}$ elements (for each left coset $l\in G/A$, fix some $g_l\in G$ such that $g_lA=l$, and then, if you fix $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$, $V'$ is spanned by the elements of the form $g_lw$ ($l\in G/A$)). Therefore, $\dim(V')\leqslant\frac{|G|}{|A|}$.